# Performance issue with update query after adding index

Tags: mysql, oracle11g

I have added the index to my update query and by adding the same query start taking several hours to complete the process.While without index its completing in some minutes i have added the index to faster the process but it became very slow exactly opposite to my desire.
Below is sample code snippet of my code.

```
Cursor c_updt_stg_rsn is
   select distinct substr(r.state_claim_id, 1, 12), ROWID
    from nemis.stg_state_resp_rsn r
    WHERE  r.seq_resp_plan_id = v_seq_resp_plan_id
   and r.submitted_claim_id is null
   and r.filler_2 is null;

  BEGIN

  OPEN c_updt_stg_rsn;
  LOOP

    FETCH c_updt_stg_rsn BULK COLLECT
      INTO v_state_claim_id, v_rowid LIMIT c_BULK_SIZE;

    FORALL i IN 1 .. v_state_claim_id.COUNT()

      UPDATE /*+ index(STG_STATE_RESP_RSN,IDX2_STG_STATE_RESP_RSN) */ nemis.stg_state_resp_rsn
         SET (submitted_claim_id , filler_2) = (SELECT DISTINCT submitted_claim_id, sl_group_id FROM nemis.state_sub_Resp_dtl D WHERE 
                                                                                       (d.state, d.type_of_claim) in (select distinct state, type_of_claim
                                                                                                                      from nemis.resp_match_state
                                                                                                                      where seq_resp_match_table_level_id in
                                                                                                                       (select seq_resp_match_table_level_id
                                                                                                                        from nemis.resp_match_table_level
                                                                                                                        where seq_resp_plan_id = v_seq_resp_plan_id))
                                                                                                                        AND resp_state_claim_id LIKE v_state_claim_id(i)||'%'
                                                                                                                       )
       WHERE  ROWID = v_rowid(i);

    IF v_state_claim_id.COUNT() != 0 THEN
      v_cnt_rsn := v_cnt_rsn + SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    END IF;
   COMMIT;
    EXIT WHEN c_updt_stg_rsn%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_updt_stg_rsn;
```

Comment: can any one please looks towards my question?

Comment: We are not wizards - you left us to guess: 1) which index you added 2)on which table 3)on which column 4) what is the original execution plan 5) what is the new/modified execution plan.  But in general i would suggest a) you to create the index (in case you think a specific index will improve performance), b) gather table performance statistics c) remove hints and let Oracle to choose the best execution plan (in 99.9% oracle knows better than you the fastest plan)